# DocumentBuilder XML file null variable issue

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception

I am using DocumentBuilder Factory in JAVA for creating an XML file and in my createTextNode() method "null" value is not acceptable.

```
Element card_number = doc.createElement("number");
        card_number.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(MYVALUE));
        card.appendChild(card_number);
```

In this piece of code if MYVALUE equals to NULL, it gives an

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:736)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:340)
```

I don't want to make an if check because I have lots of Element attribute. I can't make an if check for every single Element attribute. So, does DocumentBuilder have a setting for this issue for null variables it just writes a blank field??

Comment: No, but you can easily write your own utility routine.

Comment: How this 'Utility routine' will be looking like? Gimme a clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a utility routine to do that: I'll give you the signature:

```
void appendTextNodeIfNotNull(Element parent, String text)
```